# how to automate Jenkins task for removing a file in github

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am working on `Jenkins` automation and `Jenkins` is running in `windows server`. we are able to checkout the code from `Github` and build it.

But after the build I want to delete a `**.war` file in github from `Jenkins`.

Do we have any plugin for that in `Jenkins`?

Answer (score 1):

There should not been any `.war` binary file in the GitHub repo itself.

There are binaries in [GitHub *releases*](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/), and you can use the [GitHub Release API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#delete-a-release) to delete (and then recreate) a release if you need to cleanup the wars produced by the previous build.
(Although, if your build runs every few minutes, you probably do not want to store the build result in GitHub *every time*)
You can see one example with [this python script](https://gist.github.com/RaviH/110fae3d2b18b01ada9d#file-github_release_management-py-L52-L61).
Or you can use one of the [GitHub API libraries available](https://developer.github.com/libraries/).